# Creating a UIImageView using an NSString

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, nsstring

I have to create a number of `UIImageViews` based on values stored in an `NSString`. The value that is stored will become the name for my `UIImageView`, each one will be created individually of course.

So to keep things simple my question is, can one create a `UIImageView` based on the value stored within an `NSString`?

Rough Example:

```
-(UIImageView)createMyFruitViews:(NSString *)fruit
{
    NSString *fruit = @"";
    UIImageView *fruitImage [fruit value]; //<-- made up for example purposes.
    return fruitImage;
}
```

If this is not possible, could you please suggest a way around this?

FYI I've read through the forums too, the only thing that comes close is **[How to use NSSstring to instantiate a UIImageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815544/how-to-use-nsstring-to-instantiate-a-uiimageview)**; however I don't understand the answer and I am not sure that it can apply to what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understood what you need... as far as I can tell, you have the name of an image on a NSString object, right?

Lets say you have an array of strings, each string representing the name of an image:

```
NSArray *myImageNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"image1.png", @"image2.png", @"image3.png", nil];
```

Then you'll create your imageViews using these images:

```
for (NSString *imageName in myImageNames) {
    UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
    [self.view addSubview:myImageView];
    [myImageView release]; // If you're not using ARC
}
```

If I didn't get exactly what you need, please let me know.

Comment: This may be exactly what I need, let me give it a quick try and thanks for the quick answer. By the way you understood what I need perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Try using     `UIImageView *fruitImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:fruit]];`